# SpringBoot SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, spring-boot

I need to test my Spring application code by creating a Cucumber integration test. I am using SpringApplicationBuilder to start up my application before the actual logic is triggered and am using the following syntax to do so:-

```
application = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .parent(new Object[]{"classpath:file1.xml", "classpath:file2.xml"})
    .profiles("abc")
    .properties("name:value") [It has 5/6 (name:value) pairs here]*
    .showBanner(false)
    .logStartupInfo(true)
    .headless(true)
    .application()
    .run();
```

My Spring application starts up correctly. However, it does not get the values for the property (name, value) pairs that I am passing to the SpringApplicationBuilder(). I have tried the following to set them :-

1. Using name value pairs as above
2. List item using a HashMap of (name, value) pairs
3. Creating a ConfigurableEnvironment, retrieving the MutablePropertySources
   and setting my properties in it.

None of these options are working, so when the application starts up and the code tries to access certain System Property values, it breaks.

Any ideas how this could be fixed.. All the help is greatly appreciated! 
I need these properties to be Spring properties to make sure the app works correctly. Maybe I can test my code using the Spring props in some other way? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: How are you retrieving the environment variables?

Comment: I am not retrieving the environment variables actually.. I only need to use the Spring specific properties, which I am retrieving using annotations. So, if the Spring properties would be set correctly, the Cuke test should run as if the Spring app is triggered normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the properties as below:

```
application = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .parent(new Object[]{"classpath:file1.xml", "classpath:file2.xml"})
    .profiles("abc")
    .properties("key1:test1", "key2:test2") 
    .showBanner(false)
    .logStartupInfo(true)
    .headless(true)
    .application()
    .run();
```

Now, retrieve the properties using `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${key1}")
String val;
```

The `val` variable will be assigned the value `test1`

Comment: Thanks much for your help, but the value that I get when I do the above steps is "$key1" instead of the actual value.. Any ideas...

Comment: I am able to inject the key1 value using above code. Please share the class where you have annotated with `@Value`. Also, share the spring configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the same issue myself. 
My problem was that the keys whose values I was trying to set were also set in an *application.properties* file.

After removing the entries from the file, it worked.